# Alamofire not executing correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I have an Alamofire request that is suppose to download a file, but it will not execute the code it self. Here is the Alamofire Code:

```
var testNumbers: Int = 0
var testString: String = "Hi"
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://www.sayweee.com/admin_groupbuy/export_deal_orders/71w4o?format=csv") { temporaryURL, response in
            
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
            let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename  

            print("1")
            testNumbers = 1  

            print(directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)) 

            print("blah")
            testString = "blah"
            print("2")
            testNumbers = 2  

            return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
            
        }
print(testNumbers)
print(testString)
```

Executing this code will print this in the console:

```
 0
 Hi
```

I am pretty sure this means that the code within the `{}` are not getting executed. I've read another on this subject, and learned that Alamofire is "asynchronous", as they said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023046/alamofire-request-not-getting-executed). I've tried to get rid of everything in `viewDidLoad()` method and `viewDidAppear()` method, and made sure I didn't have any endless loops. Even after that, the results are the same. Any ideas or suggestion on why this is happening to me? I tried to look here and on Google, but I only found one post related to this topic, the one linked above.

Comment: it works fine, check it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I put your code to run in Demo Alamofire found running results and what you said is the same, as shown in the figure below:

`0
Hi
2015-12-30 14:31:29.873 iOS Example[3966:142688] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`

According to the prompt you will see that the problem:

`App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`

The solution is as follows(In the project file "info.plist" ):

`In project's "info.plist" file to add a "NSAppTransportSecurity" dictionary, an element is added in the dictionary.Key for "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads", the value is: YES, make it back to the HTTP protocol for the time being.`

The problem solution links:

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

The final results are as follows:

`0
Hi
1
file:///Users/yangshebing/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/151CB429-29B3-46D0-AFF5-37D5B8D9E4FC/data/Containers/Data/Application/756A32D1-64C5-48CF-B652-D3009D80780D/Documents/71w4o.html
blah
2`

Specific problems you can go to query the apple official documentation, query iOS9 ATS adaptation problem.

The hope can help you!

Comment: Thank you. Even though your answer did not help me fix the problem because my problem was different, I appreciate your efforts to test and explain the problem. My program was actually encountering another error before the print commands were displayed. That stopped the program. Now I added a while loop to wait for the download to finish before going on so now it works. Nonetheless, your answers could be helpful to future visitors of this thread. Thank you.